# ($f:R\subset \Bbb R^n\to \Bbb R$, $f\geq 0$, $\int\limits_R f(x)\,dx=0$) $\implies$ ($f=0$ almost everywhere)

Tags: integration, measure-theory, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

I want to prove the following

> If $R\subset \Bbb R^m$ is a $m$-dimensional rectangle and $f:R\to \Bbb R$ is a non-negative integrable function with $\displaystyle \int\limits_R f(x)\,dx=0$, then $f$ is zero almost everywhere (i.e. the set $\mathrm{supp}(f)=\{x\in R\,|\, f(x)>0\}$ has zero measure).

Here is my try:

For each $n\in \Bbb N$, define $S_n=\left\{x\in R\,|\, f(x)>\dfrac{1}{n}\right\}$. We see that $\displaystyle\mathrm{supp}(f)=\bigcup_{n\in \Bbb N}S_n$ and, since countable unions of zero measure sets is itself a zero measure set, we are done IF we show that each $S_n$ has zero measure. We have
$$0=\int\limits_Rf(x)\,dx\geq \int\limits_{S_n}f(x)\,dx\geq \int\limits_{S_n}\frac{1}{n}\,dx=\frac{1}{n}\int\limits_{S_n}\,dx=\frac{1}{n}\mu(S_n),$$
and, therefore, we must necessarily have $\mu(S_n)=0$.

That is my argument. But after thinking a while, I've thought: "But hey! Who said that such integral $\displaystyle \int\limits_{S_n}\,dx$ does exist?" I mean,  what is the negation of the claim

> "$A$ has zero measure"?

I was tempted to say: "$A$ has *positive* measure". But, what if $A$ *has not measure at all*? (i.e. $\displaystyle \int_A\,dx$ does not exist)

So, what's the proper way to prove this fact, if it is true indeed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a proof that $S_n$ has measure zero, in the context of multivariable calculus.

Given a bounded function $f:R\to \Bbb R$ on a rectangle $R\subset \Bbb R^m$, we know that the lower and upper integrals $\displaystyle\underline{\int}\limits_Rf(x)\,dx$ and $\displaystyle\overline{\int}\limits_R f(x)\,dx$ always exist and $f$ is integrable if $\displaystyle\underline{\int}\limits_R f(x)\,dx=\displaystyle\overline{\int}\limits_R f(x)\,dx:=\int\limits_Rf(x)\,dx$.

Denote $\chi_{n}:R\to \Bbb R$ the characteristic function of $S_n\subset R$. We have

$$\begin{align*}
0\leq \overline{\int}\limits_{S_n}\,dx&:=
\overline{\int}\limits_R\chi_{n}(x)\,dx=n\overline{\int}\limits_{R}\frac{1}{n}\chi_n(x)\,dx\leq n\overline{\int}\limits_{R}f(x)\chi_n(x)\,dx\\
&\leq n\overline{\int}\limits_{R}f(x)\,dx=n\int\limits_{R}f(x)\,dx=0.
\end{align*}$$

Therefore, 
$$\exists \overline{\int}\limits_{S_n}\,dx=0.$$

Let's note now that this implies that $S_n$ has zero measure in the sense of multivariable calculus.

Let $\epsilon>0$ be given. Since
$$\overline{\int}\limits_R \chi_n(x)\,dx=\inf \{U(\chi_n;P)\,:\, P \text{ is a partition of } R\},$$
and $U(\chi_n;P)\geq0$, for all $P$, the fact $\displaystyle\overline{\int}\limits_R \chi_n(x)\,dx=0$ implies that, there is some partition $P_0$ of $R$ so that
$$U(\chi_n;P_0)=\sum_{A\in P_0}M_{A}(\chi_n)\mathrm{vol}(A)<\epsilon,$$
with $M_A(\chi_n)=\sup\{\chi_n(x)\,:\, x\in A\}$. Define $$B=\{A\in P_0\,:\, A\cap S_n\neq \varnothing\}.$$

Then $B$ is a finite collection of rectangles such that $S_n\subset \displaystyle \bigcup_{A\in B}A$ and
$$\sum_{A\in B}\mathrm{vol}(A)=\sum_{A\in P_0}M_A(\chi_n)\mathrm{vol}(A)<\epsilon,$$
and this is exactly the definition of "$S_n$ has zero measure" in multivariable calculus (in this case $S_n$ is bounded, in the general case the definition requires the existence of a countable collection of rectangles such that the series sum of their volumes converge and is less than $\epsilon$).

Answer (score 1):

Well the $S_n$ are measurable subsets, since they are preimages of a measurable function of  measurable sets: $S_n=f^{-1}((1/n,\infty])$ (moreover R is measurable as a rectangle).Hence $vol(S_n)=\int_adx$ does exist (it may be infinite though, but you already showed that this cannot hold true here).

Comment: But why are they measurable? This is the central question...

Edit: Thank you for your edit, @crankk!

Comment: They are preimages of measurable subsets aren't they? Do I oversee something?

Comment: Well, does the existence of $\int\limits_Rf(x)\,dx$ implies that $f$ is measurable? The definition of a measurable function is not exactly that... See here https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Measurable_function

Edit: Remark: I am using the Riemann sums definition for this integral, as we do in multivariable calculus...

Comment: You are assuming $f$ to be integrable. A function is called integrable if it is measurable and $\int |f| < \infty$. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_integration#Measure_theory

Comment: This is the problem @crankk : I am assuming $f$ to be integrable if its Riemann sums "converge", in the usual partitions sense. Are these definitions equivalent?